# Heterogeneous Lists in Python MongoEngine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, nosql

does [MongoEngine](http://docs.mongoengine.org/) supports having different data types in a list? For example, I'd like a `ListField()` to store `IntField()` as well as `StringField()`. Is there a way to do this in MongoEngine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ListField` does not enforce a datatype unless you ask it to. However if you do then it has to be a single datatype at the moment. For example

This works:

```py
import mongoengine as mdb
class Stuff(mdb.Document):
    things = mdb.ListField()

s = Stuff(things=['1',2,[4,5]])
s.save()
```

this throws `TypeError` as it is enforcing a datatype:

```
import mongoengine as mdb
class Stuff(mdb.Document):
    things = mdb.ListField(mdb.IntField())

s = Stuff(things=['1',2,[4,5]])
s.save()
```

this throws `AttributeError` as it is expecting a Field as the first argument:

```
import mongoengine as mdb
class Stuff(mdb.Document):
    things = mdb.ListField([mdb.IntField(),mdb.StringField(),mdb.ListField()])

s = Stuff(things=['1',2,[4,5]])
s.save()
```

I can see the final example being a useful so you might want to file [an issue](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues) on the project repo.